# Clear DIV with Jquery except one element with his children

Tags: jquery, html

I know that there is many topics about that. In this topics mostly written about removing except one element,but it's children is removing too.

So what I have:

```
<div id='maindiv'>
    <div id='dont want to remove'>
        <div class= "don't want to remove"></div>
        <div class= "dont want to remove"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="want to delete"></div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to do this with Jquery:

```
$('#maindiv').find('*:not("#dont want to remove")').remove();
```

When I do this I have this without any children.

```
 <div id='maindiv'>
        <div id='dont want to remove'>
        </div>
 </div>
```

Thanks for attention. Have a nice day.

Comment: I think you're trying to keep the "don't want to remove" class (although that's technically multiple classes) But you're using the `#` which checks for IDs. Use a `.` such as `.dontWantToRemove` to select a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use:

```
$('#maindiv').children(':not(.dont_want_to_remove)').remove();
```

I use **children** instead of **find**, find is recursive and that is why it deletes the inner elements

please also note that I use the class "dont_want_to_remove" (or you can stick with ID if you prefer) **without spaces**!

Answer (score 1):

This is difficult (if not impossible) with a selector.

Instead, you could add a "dontremove" class to the element and all its elements, then remove all elements that don't have that class:

```js
//add dontremove class to ID and all its descendants:
$('#dontwanttoremove, #dontwanttoremove *').addClass('dontremove');                  

//remove all elements without the dontremove class
$('#maindiv :not(.dontremove)').remove();   

//clean up
$('.dontremove').removeClass('dontremove');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='maindiv'>
  <div id='dontwanttoremove'>
    <div>Keep me 1</div>
    <div>Keep me 2</div>
    Keep me 3
  </div>
  <div id="wanttodelete">Delete me</div>
</div>
```